# Construct a list from dataset of values and value counts

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

To expand the data `Score` into a list of `Scores` based on the `Count`, is there a better way in `pandas` and `numpy` than the following?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "Count": [1, 3, 2],
    "Score": [2, 5, 8]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

scores = []

for c, s in zip(df['Count'], df['Score']):
    for i in range(0, c):
        scores.append(s)

print(scores)
```

Expected output:

`[2, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`pd.series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html):

```
df['Score'].repeat(df['Count']).tolist()
```

Or [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
np.repeat(df['Score'],df['Count']).tolist()
```

Or [`pd.Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html):

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Count']),'Score'].tolist()
```

---

```
[2, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8]
```